# Seagate external hard disk creating problems

Tags: automounting, external-hdd, rsyslog

I've bought a new hard disk, a Seagate (Backup Plus), but I'm having problems with it.

Firstly, it doesn't mounts every time I plug it in. In such cases, I've got to restart the machine to work with it.

Secondly, whenever removing it, the `rsyslogd` and `kworker` commands go berserk , hogging the CPU and the `rsyslogd` command writes this to the `/var/log/syslog` file:

> cmd urb submission failed

My observations: for the first problem of mounting ,I tried to mount it manually but this was the result of `dmesg`:

```
[ 3791.677885] usb 1-1.1: >new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[ 3791.831989] usb 1-1.1: >New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=a013
[ 3791.831995] usb 1-1.1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 3791.831998] usb 1-1.1: >Product: Backup+ BK
[ 3791.832001] usb 1-1.1: >Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 3791.832003] usb 1-1.1: >SerialNumber: NA533ZTL
[ 3791.832846] scsi7 : uas
[ 3791.834099] scsi 7:0:0:0: >Direct-Access Seagate Backup+ BK 0410 PQ: 0   ANSI: 6
[ 3791.834843] sd 7:0:0:0: >Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 3791.835062] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 3792.835724] ....ready
[ 3795.843334] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[ 3796.014772] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 3796.014783] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[ 3796.015652] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3796.026527] sdc: sdc1
[ 3796.029091] sd 7:0:0:0: >[sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 3826.329960] sd 7:0:0:0: >uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
[ 3826.329973] sd 7:0:0:0: >uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3826.329981] sd 7:0:0:0: >uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3826.329985] sd 7:0:0:0: >uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3826.333953] usb 1-1.1: >URB BAD STATUS -71
[ 3826.402029] usb 1-1.1: >reset high-speed USB device number 5 using  ehci_hcd
[ 3826.555545] sd 7:0:0:0: >Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

One more observation is that it works fine when I start the laptop with the drive already attached. It neither has the auto mount problem , nor the CPU hogging problem.

Comment: It's mint 14 nadia 
kernel version is: 3.5.0.17
it's same for other ports also.

Comment: didn't help. @don_crissti

Comment: @deathholes did you ever resolve this issue? I am seeing it with the same Seagate disk on a QNAP NAS :(

Comment: I've changed my Os to saucy, the problem was the uas module. Every time I had to rmmod the uas module before  plugging the hard disk. Alternatively you can update the kernel to latest one where the uas is not there

Comment: Facing this in Ubuntu 12.04. When I try rmmod uas, it says module is in used.